# Custom BitmapField bug on unfocus and scroll (BlackBerry)

Tags: blackberry, java-me, focus, blackberry-os6, bitmapfield

I have been having this annoying problem when trying to implement a picture gallery on BlackBerry 6.

Everything works, however when the focus changes from the top buttons to say the pictures further down the screen, the images seem to glitch and not paint themselves correctly. Please see the images below for an example:

(Focus is on the top of the screen(not shown))
[image: initial screen]

(Focus is now on the bottom left image, note that the top image is now blank for an unknown reason)

[image: after scroll screen]

And this happens no matter how many pictures I add to the tumbnail gallery.

Now here is my code, (a part of it concerning the drawing of the thumbnails)

```
public ProductImage(String productName){
    super(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

    currentProduct = productName;

    createGUI(); 
}
public void createGUI(){
    deleteAll();
    try{
        Storage.loadPicture();
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.setTitle(new LabelField(_resources.getString(PRODUCT_IMAGE), Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
    if(ToolbarManager.isToolbarSupported())
    {
        Toolbar tb = new Toolbar();
        setToolbar(tb.createToolBar());
    }
    else{
        Toolbar tb = new Toolbar();
        add(tb.createNavBar());
    }

    picVector = Storage.getPicture(currentProduct);

    EncodedImage enc = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("camera.png");
    EncodedImage sizeEnc = ImageResizer.sizeImage(enc, Display.getHeight(), Display.getHeight());

    takenPicture = new BitmapField(enc.getBitmap());

    vfMain = new VerticalFieldManager();
    vfMain.add(logo);
    vfMain.add(new SeparatorField());
    add(vfMain);
    prepareBmpFields();
}   

 private void prepareBmpFields() {

        System.out.println("This is the vector size: " + picVector.getPicVector().size());

        LayoutManager manager = new LayoutManager();


        FieldChangeListener itemListener = new ButtonListener(); 


        mBmpFields = new ImageButtonField[picVector.getPicVector().size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < picVector.getPicVector().size(); i++) {
                /*EncodedImage image = EncodedImage
                                .getEncodedImageResource((String)imageVector.elementAt(i));*/
            byte[] data = getData((String)picVector.getPicVector().elementAt(i));
            //Encode and Resize image 
            EncodedImage  eImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data,0,data.length);

             eImage = ImageResizer.resizeImage(eImage, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
             ImageButtonField currentImage = new ImageButtonField(eImage.getBitmap());
             currentImage.setAssociatedPath((String)picVector.getPicVector().elementAt(i));
             mBmpFields[i] = currentImage;
             mBmpFields[i].setChangeListener(itemListener);
             manager.add(mBmpFields[i]);

        }
        vfMain.add(manager);
    }

    private class LayoutManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
        public LayoutManager() {
            super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
        }

        protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
            int columns = mScrWidth / (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin);

            int scrWidth = Display.getWidth();

              int rows = mBmpFields.length / columns
                + (mBmpFields.length % columns > 0 ? 1 : 0);
              int counter = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                int posX = j * (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
                int posY = i * (mImgHeight + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;

                if(mBmpFields.length > counter){
                    Field field = mBmpFields[counter];
                    layoutChild(field, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
                    setPositionChild(field, posX, posY);
                    counter++;
                };
               }  
             }
              if(Display.getWidth() < Display.getHeight()){
                setExtent(mScrWidth, (int)(mScrHeight*1.25));
                }
              else{
                  setExtent(mScrWidth, (int)(mScrHeight*2)); 
              }
        }


        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return mScrWidth;
        }
        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            return mScrHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed many non relevant parts of the code, but the needed code is there.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? Thanks for your help!

Edit: as requested, here is my implementation of ImageButtonField class:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Characters;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;

public class ImageButtonField extends BitmapField{

String associatedPath ="";
BitmapField image2;

public ImageButtonField(Bitmap image) {
    super(image);
}
public void setAssociatedPath(String path){
    associatedPath = path;
}
public String getAssociatedPath(){
    return associatedPath;
}
public boolean isFocusable() {
    return true;
}
protected void applyTheme(Graphics arg0, boolean arg1) {
}

protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
}
protected void onFocus(int direction) {
      // only change appearance if this button is enabled (aka editable)
      if (isEditable()) {
         invalidate();  // repaint
      } 
      super.onFocus(direction);
   }

   public void onUnfocus() {
      invalidate();  // repaint
      super.onUnfocus();
   }
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}

protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paint(graphics);
    if (isFocus()) {
        graphics.setGlobalAlpha(128);
        graphics.setColor(0x888888);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }else{
        graphics.setGlobalAlpha(0);
        graphics.setColor(0x000000);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        //graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), image2.getB, 0, 0);
    }
}

protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) {
    if(Characters.ENTER == character || Characters.SPACE == character) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }
    return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
}
```

}

Comment: just wanted to let you know that I can reproduce the problem.  I'm looking at it now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can disregard my first answer, but since I didn't have your `ImageButtonField` code at the time, I don't want to throw it out ... maybe someone else will find it useful.

In the end, I didn't need to make any changes to `ImageButtonField`, but I did change your `LayoutManager` class.  The way I figured out that it was the problem was I just started replacing your custom UI classes with built-in ones.  I replaced `ImageButtonField` with `BitmapField`.  That didn't fix it.  Then, I replaced `LayoutManager` with `FlowFieldManager` and that fixed it.  So, I knew where the problem was.

My solution:

```
private class LayoutManager extends Manager {
  public LayoutManager() {
     super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
  }

  protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
     setExtent(width, height);
     // TODO: maybe always set the same virtual extent?
     if (Display.getWidth() < Display.getHeight()) {
        setVirtualExtent(mScrWidth, (int) (mScrHeight * 1.25));
     } else {
        setVirtualExtent(mScrWidth, (int) (mScrHeight * 2));
     }

     int columns = mScrWidth / (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin);
     // int scrWidth = Display.getWidth();

     int rows = mBmpFields.length / columns + (mBmpFields.length % columns > 0 ? 1 : 0);
     int counter = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
           int posX = j * (mImgWidth + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;
           int posY = i * (mImgHeight + 2 * mImgMargin) + mImgMargin;

           if (mBmpFields.length > counter) {
              Field field = mBmpFields[counter];
              layoutChild(field, mImgWidth, mImgHeight);
              setPositionChild(field, posX, posY);
              counter++;
           }
        }
     }
  }

  public int getPreferredWidth() {
     return mScrWidth;
  }

  public int getPreferredHeight() {
     return mScrHeight;
  }
}
```

I can't say for sure that I understand why your original code wasn't working, but I can say that I wouldn't have done a few of the things in the original code:

1. The original code was extending `VerticalFieldManager` but was doing all the work itself, in `sublayout()`. So, I don't think there was any point extending `VerticalFieldManager`.  I changed it to just extend `Manager`.
2. The original code was calling `setExtent()` with different sizes.  I don't think that's what you wanted.  **Extent** is the actual size of the `Field`.  **Virtual extent** is the virtual size, which is what you want to set larger than the actual extent, in order to enable scrolling.  You don't need to dynamically calculate different **extents** for portrait vs. landscape because the `width` and `height` parameters passed to `sublayout()` will already reflect that.  I'm not sure you really even need to be setting different virtual extents either.  I think you should probably **always** set the virtual extent height to the number of rows times picture height, accounting for margins.
3. You had an unused variable `scrWidth` in your original code.  I commented it out above.

Comment: This did the job, works very well now! Thanks for putting the effort into this, doubt I would of figured it out myself!!

Comment: @BananaMan, No worries, mate.  I know the legacy BlackBerry UI classes can be tricky to sort out, and I admit that I had to resort to simple trial and error in order to narrow down where the issue was.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You also [posted this question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263949/how-to-highlight-focused-custom-buttonfield-imagebuttonfield-on-blackberry), right?  Am I correct in assuming that the `ImageButtonField` you refer to here is the same one you were working on in the other question?

I can't see your full implementation of `ImageButtonField`, which you should probably post here, too.  However, looking at the answers to your other question, I have a feeling that you're doing some custom focus handling in `ImageButtonField`, and maybe it's not being done quite right.  In any case, that class may be where the problem is.

I have a similar `Field` subclass of my own, and here are the focus handling methods I define:

```java
public class CustomButtonField extends Field {

   private Bitmap _button;    // the currently displayed button image
   private Bitmap _on;        // image for 'on' state (aka in-focus)
   private Bitmap _off;       // image for 'off' state (aka out-of-focus)

   protected void onFocus(int direction) {
      // only change appearance if this button is enabled (aka editable)
      if (isEditable()) {
         _button = _on;
         invalidate();  // repaint
      } 
      super.onFocus(direction);
   }

   protected void onUnfocus() {
      _button = _off;
      invalidate();  // repaint
      super.onUnfocus();
   }

   protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
      // override superclass implementation and do nothing
   }

   public boolean isFocusable() {
      return true;
   }
```

I also have a custom implementation of `paint()`.  I won't show it all here, because a lot of the code probably has nothing to do with your problem, but my `paint()` does include this call:

```java
graphics.drawBitmap(_padding, _padding, _fieldWidth, _fieldHeight, _button, 0, 0);
```

You might not care about the fact that I have separate images for focused, and unfocused states ... maybe you show the same image at all times.

But, probably the thing to check is your `onFocus()` and `onUnfocus()` methods.  You may need to add a call to `invalidate()` as I have.

Looking at Rupak's answer to your other question, it would also be good to check your `ImageButtonField.paint()` method, and make sure you aren't neglecting to do important drawing steps if the field is not in focus.

Comment: I will try a few things in my ImageButtonField class, if nothing works I will post my original ImageButtonField class. Thanks for the response, will update shortly!

Comment: Well I have tried a few things but none of my modifications seemed to fix the problem. I have added my ImageButtonField implementation to the question.

Comment: @BananaMan  Thanks.  I'll try again tonight with your ImageButtonField code.

Comment: haha no need to thank me, you're the one helping me out! thank you.

Comment: @BananaMan, just thanking you for posting the code.  A lot of new users just post questions with insufficient information, and then go radio silent when you ask for clarification.  A nice thorough question helps you, helps me help you, and helps the community get more value out of the site in the future :)