# Image gone After Focusing

Tags: blackberry, focus, buttonfield

[This](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg20/scaled.php?server=20&filename=beforedocus.png&res=landing) is before focus state. It work fine.

[This](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg594/scaled.php?server=594&filename=focusing.png&res=landing) is on focusing state. It work fine.

[This](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg833/scaled.php?server=833&filename=afterfocus.png&res=landing) is after focus state. It occurred problem where the image gone.

It works fine for the top right but top left image got problem.

Here is my custom `VerticalFieldManager`:

```java
public class Custom_TopField extends HorizontalFieldManager implements
    FieldChangeListener {

private Bitmap bg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("header_bar.png");
private Bitmap download = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn_download.png");
private Bitmap downloadactive = Bitmap
        .getBitmapResource("btn_download_active.png");
private Bitmap refresh = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon_refresh.png");
private Bitmap refreshactive = Bitmap
        .getBitmapResource("icon_refresh_active.png");
private Bitmap back = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn_back.png");
private Bitmap backctive = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn_back_active.png");
private Bitmap news = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon_news.png");
private Bitmap newsactive = Bitmap
        .getBitmapResource("icon_news_active.png");

private Custom_ButtonField downloadbtn, refreshbtn, backbtn, newsbtn;
private Custom_LabelField title;

Custom_TopField(final MainScreen mainscreen) {
    Background background = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bg);
    setBackground(background);
    title = new Custom_LabelField("东方日报", DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS
            | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.HCENTER
            | Field.FOCUSABLE, Color.WHITE) {
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Main_AllLatestNews());
            Main.getUiApplication().popScreen(mainscreen);
            return true;
        }
    };
    title.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 33));
    add(title);

    downloadbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(download, downloadactive,
            downloadactive);
    downloadbtn.setChangeListener(this);
    add(downloadbtn);

    refreshbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(refresh, refreshactive,
            refreshactive);
    refreshbtn.setChangeListener(this);
    add(refreshbtn);

    backbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(back, backctive, backctive);
    backbtn.setChangeListener(this);
    add(backbtn);

    /*newsbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(news, newsactive, newsactive);
    newsbtn.setChangeListener(this);
    add(newsbtn);*/
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
    Field field = getField(0);
    layoutChild(field, 120, Font.getDefault().getHeight());
    setPositionChild(field, (getPreferredWidth() - title.getWidth()) / 2,
            15);

    field = getField(1);
    layoutChild(field, download.getWidth(), download.getHeight());
    setPositionChild(field, getPreferredWidth()
            - (download.getWidth() + 10),
            getPreferredHeight() - (download.getHeight() + 5));

    field = getField(2);
    layoutChild(field, refresh.getWidth(), refresh.getHeight());
    setPositionChild(field,
            getPreferredWidth() - (refresh.getWidth() + 10),
            getPreferredHeight() - (refresh.getHeight() + 5));

    field = getField(3);
    layoutChild(field, back.getWidth(), back.getHeight());
    setPositionChild(field, 10, 5);

    /*field = getField(4);
    layoutChild(field, news.getWidth(), news.getHeight());
    setPositionChild(field, 10, 5);*/

    width = Math.min(width, getPreferredWidth());
    height = Math.min(height, getPreferredHeight());
    setExtent(width, height);
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return 70;
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return Display.getWidth();
}

public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int rectHeight = getPreferredHeight();
    int rectWidth = getPreferredWidth();

    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
    super.paint(graphics);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    if (field == downloadbtn) {

    } else if (field == refreshbtn) {

    } else if (field == backbtn) {

    } else if (field == newsbtn) {

    }
}
}
```

Here is `custom button field`

```
public class Custom_ButtonField extends ButtonField {
Bitmap mNormal;
Bitmap mFocused;
Bitmap mActive;

int mWidth;
int mHeight;

private int color = -1;
String text;

public Custom_ButtonField(Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused, Bitmap active) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE);
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}

public Custom_ButtonField(String text, Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused,
        Bitmap active, int color) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK | Field.FOCUSABLE);
    this.color = color;
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE,
            BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    this.text = text;
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    super.onFocus(direction);
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    super.onUnfocus();
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    switch (getVisualState()) {
    case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
        bitmap = mNormal;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
        bitmap = mFocused;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
        bitmap = mActive;
        break;
    default:
        bitmap = mNormal;
    }
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            bitmap, 0, 0);
    graphics.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 25));
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.drawText(text, (mNormal.getWidth() - Font.getDefault()
            .getAdvance(text)) / 2, ((mNormal.getHeight() - Font
            .getDefault().getHeight()) / 2) + 10, DrawStyle.HCENTER
            | DrawStyle.VCENTER);
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
}
}
```

Comment: Paste the implementation of `Custom_ButtonField`. Make sure that no image passed to `Custom_ButtonField` isn't null.

Comment: @Rupak, I had updated the code

Comment: I am sure that no image is null, all existed

Comment: Are you facing the problem only for the first button `downloadbtn`?
If yes then try to initialize downloadbtn, and refreshbtn exactly as `backbtn = new Custom_ButtonField(back, backctive, backctive);`.

Comment: @Rupak, you can see, i initialize with same custom class but just different image only. back and news will disappear while download and refresh will not

Comment: I replace `refresh` with `back` and `refreshactive` with `backactive`. However, the right side work fine but left side still will gone after focus.

Comment: Again why not to try use setBackground() method with image?

Comment: setbackground only can set one fix image, but i want change image when focusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the second problem just like this [I've seen in the last couple weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060070/119114).

### Background

To understand the solution, first you should understand the basic UI classes in BlackBerry.

First, we have [the `Field` class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html).  A `Field` is the base class of the normal UI *components*.  If you write a UI component yourself, **from scratch**, then you would subclass `Field`:

```java
public class MyWidget extends Field {
```

However, if there already exists a BlackBerry class that does almost what you need, and you just need to change its behaviour a bit, then you would subclass something else.  For example:

```java
public class MyButtonWidget extends ButtonField {
```

The same pattern exists for the [`Manager` class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html).  If you are writing a `Manager` **from scratch**, then extend `Manager`:

```java
public class MyManager extends Manager {
```

which [involves doing this, according to the BlackBerry docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html):

> **Implementing your own layout manager**
>
> If you have particular needs, you
>   can implement your own manager. Extend the Manager class, and
>   implement sublayout, getPreferredWidth, and getPreferredHeight. For
>   efficiency, you may optionally override subpaint.

However, if an existing Manager **subclass** already does most of what you need, and you just want to customize it, then you might consider extending that subclass:

```java
public class MyHorizontalManager extends HorizontalFieldManager {
```

In your case, your `Custom_TopField` is doing **all** of the required work for a fully custom `Manager` (see the highlighted quote above from the javadocs).  So, there's not really any reason for you to **extend** `HorizontalFieldManager`.  A `HorizontalFieldManager` is used when you just want to `add()` your fields, and have them all laid out horizontally.  But, you do that explicitly in your `sublayout()` code. As it turns out, it looks like your logic is competing with the base class.

### Solution

So, what you should do, is have your class just extend `Manager`:

```java
public class Custom_TopField extends Manager implements FieldChangeListener {
```

If you do that, you will need to call a different super constructor.  Something like this (you might want to pick different style constants depending on your needs):

```java
Custom_TopField(final MainScreen mainscreen) {
   super(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
```

Another alternative would be to simply not implement `sublayout()`, extend `HorizontalFieldManager` like you originally had, and then control layout with the child fields' **margins** and `long` **style** flags.  But, since the solution I gave above requires only changing 2 lines of code, that's probably the easiest for you this time.

### Other Problem(s)

I also noticed in your code, and screenshots, that the **Download** button doesn't show up.  I don't know the exact size of all your png images, but if the refresh and download images are the same size, then your current logic is just laying out the refresh button right over the download button.  So, the download button is hidden.  That's probably not what you want?

Comment: its work again, thanks dude. I changed to `extends Manager`. The four button is same size and 2 at left while 2 at right. I got `if-else` to control the display of 1 left 1 right.